# How can you reference to javascript window element before initianization?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

This example is borrowed from Backbone directory demo app
https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-directory/blob/master/web/js/utils.js#L11

```
// The Template Loader. Used to asynchronously load templates located in separate .html files
window.templateLoader = {

    load: function(views, callback) {

        var deferreds = [];

        $.each(views, function(index, view) {
            if (window[view]) {
                deferreds.push($.get('tpl/' + view + '.html', function(data) {
                    window[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
                }, 'html'));
            } else {
                alert(view + " not found");
            }
        });

        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
    }  
};
```

You initialize this with array of strings [views] and [callback] function.

My question is how window[view] (click above link to exact position in the code) can be checked if (as far as I see) wasn't be initialized previously? If I'm not precise please write this in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, then when you call `templateLoader.load` you pass in 2 arguments; `views` and `callback`. We can assume that `views` is an array, since we then iterate over that array with the jQuery `.each()` method. The callback to `.each()` is passed the element of the `views` array that corresponds to the current iteration. That argument is named `view`.

So `view` is some arbitrary value that was stored in the `views` array. We then try to find a property of `window` with the identifier that matches the value of `view`. If `view === "james"` we are looking for `window.james`.

If you look at some of the views in that app you will see that they are defined like this:

```
window.ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // Some methods
});
```

So `ContactView` is a property of `window`, and we could call `templateLoader.load` like the following to load that template:

```
templateLoader.load(["ContactView"], someCallbackFn);
```

And you can see where that actually gets called in [*main.js*](https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-directory/blob/master/web/js/main.js).

So what's actually happening is a bunch of properties of `window` are defined in various other files, and then loaded by the template loader, by passing an array of identifiers to it.

Comment: Excellent! I just realize this minutes ago.. So app is loading views first then utli.js starts to work and all window.VIEWS are allready loaded. Thanks very much..

Views loading: https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-directory/blob/master/web/index.html#L36

window setting up : https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-directory/blob/master/web/js/views/header.js#L1